# Why will my PowerShell profile only load for the 32bit version of powershell?

Tags: powershell

As per this document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx I've created a profile in:

```
%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

The profile only contains a basic function for testing.

When I run the 64 bit version of PowerShell the profile doesn't load. PowerShell returns an error when I try to call the test function.

When I run the x86 version the profile loads correctly and I can call the function.

I've tested this on several 64 bit machines and get the same result every time.

How can I get my profile to load correctly in the 64bit version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the 64 bit instance of PowerShell and create the profile. The files are saved in different locations: 64b - c:\windows\system32, 32b (c:\windows\SysWOW64).

Comment: The profile is created in the right place. Calling Test-Path $Profile.AllUsersCurrentHost returns True.  Also, when you create a profile in c:\windows\system32... it automatically gets copied across to c:\windows\SysWOW64...  So there is a copy in both locations

Comment: Thanks for the info. What error do you get when you call the function? Does your execution policy permits running scripts?

Comment: Yes. Execution policy is set to unrestricted. The error message is the standard 'The term 'Test-Function' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet...'

Comment: Ty this from a 64b instance, do you get 'hi'? $file = new-item -path $PROFILE.AllUsersCurrentHost -value "function prof {'hi'}" -type file -force; . $file.fullname; prof

Comment: Amazing. It works!  Any idea why?  When I edit the file manually none of the changes are picked up by PowerShell when it's restarted. does the file have to be created and edited via a script?

Comment: Don't worry... I'm seeing some very strange behaviour when editing via notepad++. Editing in notepad seems to work as expected. Colleagues are baffled. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your notepad++ is a 32-bit application probably, hence when writing to c:\windows\system32, it's really writing to the redirected c:\windows\syswow64. As opposed to notepad.exe, a native 64-bit binary.